# Property 'remoteMessageDelegate' not found on object of type 'FIRMessaging *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with some Swift and FCM code and after updating pods I'm getting two errors. I have done research but can't figure out what to do to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
// For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
// For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
[FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd]; error message———> No visible @interface for 'FIRInstanceID' declares the selector 'setAPNSToken:type:'<--error message ends  

    NSLog(@"deviceToken1 = %@; %@",deviceToken,[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]);
}
```

Here is the error message:

> Property 'remoteMessageDelegate' not found on object of type
>   'FIRMessaging *'

Comment: I made a mistake sorry I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using?

Comment: Using Firebase (5.16.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In version 5.0.0, they removed `remoteMessageDelegate` and replaced it with `delegate`:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#5.0.0
[image: release notes 5.0.0]

It is also `delegate` now in the current `FIRMessaging` API documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#/c:objc(cs)FIRMessaging(py)delegate

> Delegate to handle FCM token refreshes, and remote data messages
>   received via FCM direct channel.
>
> `@property (readwrite, nonatomic, nullable) id<FIRMessagingDelegate>`
>   `delegate;`

You can refer to their quickstart-ios code for sample usage:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m#L36

```
  // [START set_messaging_delegate]
  [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
  // [END set_messaging_delegate]
```

Comment: Yep that fixed remoteMessageDelegate all I have left to fix is [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd]; which is giving me this error No visible @interface for 'FIRInstanceID' declares the selector 'setAPNSToken:type:'

Comment: You need to learn to read the API docs. From the release notes I linked to in my answer, they moved `setAPNSToken:type` from `FIRInstanceID` to `FIRMessaging`. If you go to the [FIRInstanceID API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/FIRInstanceID), there is no more `setAPNSToken`. It is now indeed part of [FIRMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#-setapnstokentype). It looks like you're using "old" FCM code, because a lot has changed in the current versions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll be on it ASAP.